# An intuitive approach to solving a question of geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, education, alternative-proof

> In the square $ABCD$ of side $6$, points $P$ and $Q$ move along sides $AB$ and $CB$ so that $\overline{PB}=\overline{BQ}=x$. Consider the segment $OQ$ parallel to $AB$. Which of the following expressions describes the measure of the length of $\overline{OQ}$ as a function of $x$?

[image]

**My approach:** I named, for simplicity, $\overline{OQ}=y$. I have considered that $\text{area}(\triangle PBC)=3x$; $\text{area}(PBOQ)=\frac{(x+y)\cdot x}{2}$, $\text{area}(\triangle OQC)=\frac{y\cdot (6-x)}{2}$. Hence

$$\text{area}(\triangle OQC)=\frac{y\cdot (6-x)}{2}=3x-\frac{(x+y)\cdot x}{2}$$

Solved $y$ in function of $x$ we have:

$$y=f(x)=x-\frac 16 x^2.$$

Now the question is the following: given that my 18-year-old students will have to deal with simulations from the **National Institute for the Evaluation of the Education and Training System**, how will they be able to solve the problem without pen and paper as required comprising 41 questions in an hour? I would not have succeeded without to use pen and paper.

> Is there an alternative proof instead of my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use similar triangles $\triangle COQ\cong \triangle CPB$, therefore $$\frac{\overline{OQ}}{\overline{PB}} = \frac{\overline{CQ}}{\overline{CB}} = \frac{6-x}{6}$$

So $$\overline{OQ} = \frac{x(6-x)}{6}$$

Comment: Thank you veryyyyyyyyy.....much.

Answer (score 2):

The triangles $\triangle PBC$ and $\triangle OQC$ are similar, which shows that
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{6-x}{6}.$$
It follows that
$$y=x-\frac16x^2.$$

Comment: I have thought about it late :-)...now who do I give the green tick to? :-)....Can you put the green check mark to @Just a user that have low score?

Comment: @Sebastiano Our answers are identical. I won't shed a tear if I don't get the green tick, don't worry. And I think you already gave me one a few days ago ;)

Comment: $\ddot \smile\ddot \smile\ddot \smile\ddot \smile$ I like to be corrected.